# How to check the object type when it's decorated with different xml element

Tags: c#

Please find the below Property is defined.

I have object in xml format, has multiple types decorated using xml elements. I will get a some value run time. During run time how to check the object which type it is.

```
    [XmlElement("Arithmetic", typeof(NumericDataT))]
    [XmlElement("BitEnumeration", typeof(BitEnumerationItemListT))]
    [XmlElement("Boolean", typeof(bool))]
    [XmlElement("DateTime", typeof(DateTimeDataT))]
    [XmlElement("Enumeration", typeof(EnumerationItemListT))]
    [XmlElement("MultiValueUiTemplate", typeof(UiTemplateTMultiValueUiTemplate))]
    [XmlElement("String", typeof(StringDataT))]
    public object Item
    {
        get
        {
            return _ItemField;
        }
        set
        {
            _ItemField = value;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at reflection?

Comment: No tried using reelection

Comment: You can use it to determine the type of an object or attributes. See [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/reflection-and-attributes/) for example.

Comment: the suggestion that @PeterSmith gives should be your answer